# What are the complemented subspaces of $(\bigoplus\ell_q^n)_p$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Bourgain/Casazza/Lindenstrauss/Tzafriri proved in their [unconditional basis UTAP book (1985)](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0322) that $\ell_1$ is the only nontrivial complemented subspace of $(\bigoplus\ell_2^n)_1$, and hence by duality $c_0$ is the only nontrivial complemented subspace of $(\bigoplus\ell_2^n)_0$.  And of course there are no nontrivial complemented subspaces of $(\bigoplus\ell_2^n)_p$ for $1<p<\infty$ due to the fact that it's just $\ell_p$ itself.

I am wondering about the general case where $p\neq q\neq 2$.  Is $\ell_p$ then the only nontrivial complemented subspace of $(\bigoplus\ell_q^n)_p$?

Comment: I guess you mean $p \not= 1$. I think your question is still open.

Comment: @BillJohnson Ah okay, that's unexpected.  I thought for sure this would have been solved.

But are you also saying that the question is closed for $(\oplus\ell_q^n)_1$ for $q$ other than just 2?

Comment: I just meant that when $p=1$ and $1<q \not=2 < \infty$ the space contains a complemented subspace isomorphic to the $1$ sum of $\ell_2^n$, which is not isomorphic either to $\ell_1$ or to the whole space.

Comment: @BillJohnson  Oh, yes, the complemented version of Dvoretsky.